# Please reopen a post about what's generally acceptable to ask superiors or read into the employee handbook

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed, reopen-request

The question is this:

[Is the subject of installing Steam on your office computer one which should't even be mentioned?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/36463/is-it-automatically-bad-to-install-steam-on-your-office-computer-and-run-it-duri)

This was not a company-specific question.  Even before I edited the question, it was clear that I was asking about a universal practice about whether it's generally considered acceptable to even **ask** about it in *any* workplace.  If this were company-specific, I would have just taken care of it myself and asked my superiors.

I was starting to remove this account, for several different reasons, but it's taking long enough for me to start to think about changing my mind.  But I wanted to know whether it was generally considered bad practice to even ask your bosses about this, this was clear from before I edited the question, and people shouldn't have to edit their questions and run to meta every time they don't word something with the same quality as a best-selling novel.

Please reopen.  Thanks.

(Wasn't sure to tag this with `discussion` or `support`.  One of them was basically required, so I just went with both for now.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that with the edits this question is on-topic here.  I don't think it's about company-specific policies.

I think it should be answered in an IT-agnostic way; if a company has IT policies about installing software then of course that needs to be taken into account, but otherwise, is there a stigma about games? That's a reasonable question IMO.

After the edits, the question received two reopen votes (which aged away) and three "leave closed" votes in the review queue.  I'd like to see more community support before using mod powers to unilaterally reopen.  I encourage people to take another look at vote to reopen (if you can) or comment on this meta question.  Of course, if you feel it should remain closed please also use this meta question to discuss that.

Comment: if the question gets reopened, yet another edit will be needed to wipe out "This question has been put on hold" phrase, otherwise it may confuse readers (FWIW I voted reopen)

Comment: Thank y'all, @gnat and Monica.  Monica, I've gone ahead and rewritten the question.

Comment: @Panzercrisis I just cast the last reopen vote with some minor edits - awesome work rewriting the question!

Comment: Thanks, @enderland.

Comment: @Panzercrisis, I want to echo what enderland said.  Great job on the rewrite!  Thanks for working with us on this.